# Penetrating sound through wall

Tags: acoustics, ultrasound

I'm an electronics engineer, sorry for my lack of physics knowledge.
I need an inaudible sound transmitter that can penerate through one concrete wall.

[image]

Is that possible such a thing? By the way my aim is to send human voice over ultrasound(inaudible) waves through a wall.
Sorry if i couldn't give much enough details, this is because lack of knowledge. I would be very happy if you ask guiding questions.

Comment: I am confused about what you are looking for.  The human voice is not (mostly) in the ultrasound regime; do you want a device that increases its frequency content?  That is almost certainly going to record the voice and then replay it distorted, and in this case why not just send the voice electronically?  Do you want to have the signal go back to audible frequencies on the other side of the wall?  You would need to convert the signal back again, if so.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer. I can't send the data over electomagnetic signals(RF) because of jammers always running in environment so don't permitted. I need to recover back again in human voice range at the other side of the wall as you said. You can think what i'm trying just like sending arbitrary data with inaudible ways to other side of the wall.

Comment: Something you might want to consider is that ultrasound attenuates rapidly in space.  Depending on the size of your barrier and what it is made of, you may need to blast the ultrasound at prohibitively large amplitudes.  Another option would be infrasound or elastic waves, but they have their issues as well.  How many details of your problem can you share?

Comment: I can share much more details. My origin is electronics, can you guide me i'll be very happy. I don't know where to go? What frequencies, what kind of transmitter? I just want it not to be heard.

Comment: You could experiment

Comment: I don't think that this is the proper venue for a guide like you are seeking.  I think that would be best obtained by taking appropriate classes.  What you could do is propose a specific solution and we could talk about why it will or won't work and discuss possible improvements.

Comment: Using what instruments an experiment? How an experiment? Do you have details that you wanna say?

Answer (score 3):

The main problem is not the absorption in the wall but the reflections at both interfaces wall-air. There is a huge acoustical impedance missmatch between air and solid materials so the reflection is almost complete at the interface. This is the reason they use coupling gel when you get a medical ultrasound investigation. Here you have three interfaces, the ultrasound transducer to air, air to wall and wall to air again. You could use a transducer specialy adapted to air so you only have the other two reflexions. The absorption is there too and increases with frequency.
But in principle there is nothing preventing your transmission. Maybe you put the ultrasound transducer in contact with the wall and the other sides puts their receiver in contact with the wall. If you use some gel to improve coupling, it will transmit pretty well.

Comment: Thanks for this clarification. There should be at least 2-3 meters distance between transmitter and the all in transmitter side. How about say ultrasound absorption in air? How much loss in 2-3 meters away. Also you pointed out low ultrasound frequencies about what frequencies 30-40kHz? Is there any specific trasnducer suggested by you?